# SQL Server: Use a CSV as a linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, flat-file

I need some help in configuring an SQL Server csv linked server. I already have an Excel linked server working without any problems, but each time I try to connect to my csv, I get varying error messages but the first is usually:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
> "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "CSV". (Microsoft SQL
> Server, Error: 7303)

To be clear, I'm looking to resolve the linked server issue that I'm currently facing, rather than consider alternatives such as Openrowset.

- SQL Server uses the source meta to define field data which is already a great help for data sets that can change structure and even data-type within defined row, which breaks most etl-tools.
- Much of the data I am loading includes comma-separated values within comma-delimited fields such as address data:
  `1234 Oak Tree Drive, Some Village`
  This has a tendency to break data querying with OpenRowset and without going through the rigmarole to switch the BIG 15GB+ files to text just to negate this, linked servers can help get around this.
- And Openrowset does have some limitations such as it's 8000 character maximum limit (although we can get around this by using parameters and table variables etc

SQL Server Dev edition is installed locally to my Windows 11 OS

**My environment:**

- OS: Windows 11 Home (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702])
- SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23
- Provider: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 (Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 14.0.7015.1000
  With options set: Dynamic Parameter; Allow inprocess
- User account: Windows Authent

Excel wouldn't link without setting the two options, so I'd rather not adjust these.

Finally, my two linked server configs:

**Excel**

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'EXCEL', @srvproduct=N'Excel', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'C:\datasources\excel.xlsx', @provstr=N'Excel 12.0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'EXCEL',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'EXCEL', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

**CSV**

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'CSV', @srvproduct=N'CSVFLATFILE', @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'c:\datasources\flat.csv', @provstr=N'Text;HDR=Yes'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'CSV',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CSV', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Any ideas what I've missed? I know linked servers can be problematic in their setups, though this is the first time I've experienced such a problem.

Knowing that flat file linked servers use a near identical config as Excel, I've successfully configured this first, before scripting the server and updating to CSV and then TXT for a text-based server just in case.
Excel is working as expected, but csv (and txt) aren't

Comment: What are you trying to do? Files aren't servers. Linked Servers aren't an alternative to external tables. Even with Excel, you're still using a finnicky and slow OLEDB provider with *very* limited SQL support, no indexes, limited type support (no type support in CSVs) and date/number localization issues. Why not import the data into the database and index it?

Comment: try it with the ssms and see if yout get it there https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/csv-odbc-linked-server.rst

Comment: `alternatives such as Openrowset.` that's not an alternative. It uses the *same* driver so has the same problems.

Comment: @nbk that's a third company's product that still tries to treat text files as databases

Comment: I'm trying to connect a csv to SQL Server using linked server. I've achieved this in the past on a Win10 machine, I'd like to set this up again.

Comment: That's the how, not the what. Why are you trying to use the files as tables instead of importing the data into the database? How many files, how much data is there? SSIS makes this easier and more manageable than trying to guess what a file actually contains. You can use the `Import Data` wizard to import the files *and* generate an SSIS package to execute later

Comment: And I'd rather not use a proprietary driver. CData drivers are quite expensive, and outside the realms of personal use on home PCs

Comment: Right now you're trying to use the quirkiest way possible. Hence `why`? If you have multiple millions of rows stored in Spark, Amazon or Azure you could use [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=dedicated) through Polybase. That offloads the actual processing to the remote *server cluster*.

Comment: It's like I've said, What I want to do is to read and execute SQL against a csv from SSMS using the linked server method.
What I then want to do is outside the scope of this post

Comment: Don't use the linked server method.

Comment: But I want to use the linked server method. It works, so I want to use it. I am well aware of polybase, and if I were to follow the external table method, I'd simply drop into my AWS S3 account and query over Athena.
But that isn't what I want to do. I want to use linked servers.

Comment: No it doesn't work and your question proves it

Comment: If you absolutely insist on suffering and slow performance, again try SSIS through the `Import Data Wizard` and use OLEDB for flat files as the source. That's the same driver you're trying to use. This will allow you to test settings and preview the data. You may still run into problems because the flat file source had trouble handling quoted fields with newlines in the past. Of course, after previewing the data, you could just insert them in the database

Comment: PS: data engineers just don't do what you try to do. It doesn't scale even to two files. It locks the file so you *can't* modify it.

Comment: Right, we are bordering on a discussion about the merits of linked servers vs other more modern standards which are not relevant for this discussion. Please keep to the request. Are you able to help with the config to meet my requirements? Or do you just want to educate and steer towards alternatives?

Comment: Please respect the people trying to help you. When a SQL Server MVP (former) and 20-year data engineer asks you why, or tells you that this is a bad idea, there's a reason. I already mentioned several alternatives that actually work.

Comment: Besides, 2010 is a very old version. The [latest ACE driver version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) is 2016. This may have fixed the quoting and separator issues you encountered. If you have a recent Office version on your machine, the 2016 version may exist already

Comment: It might be helpful if you try to reduce the problem to a smaller csv file and attach it through a fiddle or something

Comment: And please respect me. You do not know me, my background expertise or experience. I've already explained that I'm quite capable on using the alternatives, and as a data engineer, I would've used these in a heartbeat.
But for this personal, non-commercial project, I want to use this outdated, outmoded, slow, underperforming, memory-hogging solution. And ETL tools aren't the option right now. So please, don't insult me, or try to educate me. Just stick to the request. If this is not something you want to do, I won't hold it against you.

Comment: The data I'm working with is a single file of 2 years worth of UK Police data from around 20 years ago, so its not held in a government repo anymore. I don't really have the option to break it down into smaller chunks, but as described, if simple readability were the issue, I'd have loaded this into Athena before now.

Comment: And I do have ACE 16 installed too, but this is also running into the same issue. I also converted the working Excel file to csv (and txt) just in case it is a problem with the data, but to no avail; its definitely something with my config, especially as both SSIS and other tools can easily read the contents of the file

Comment: I haven't looked at the ACE drivers in a very long time, and I'm probably misremembering how it worked, but have you tried setting the data source to the directory containing the .csv file(s) as opposed to a specific file? i.e: `@datasrc=N'c:\datasources\'` and then `select * from [CSV]...[flat#csv]` (note the three dots).

Comment: That was it @AlwaysLearning, I had tried to test the server, but it gave a "not a valid path" error when it was clear to see that the path was valid. Recreating the linked server sans file, and it just worked

Answer (score 0):

This one was an obvious spot from @AlwaysLearning: CSV and text files are treated as tables from the same db, with the file-system folder being taken as the "DB". Therefore, instead of directing the linked server to the file like you would for Excel, this time, just connect to the folder, let the linked server do the rest.

Steve